# how to find this function is bijective?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ne 1\}$, $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}, x \ne 2\}$
and
$$f:A \to B\\f(x)=\frac{2x}{x-1}$$

How can we show that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: How to find the bijective of $f(x)$?-What do you mean???

Comment: @Aniket I'm pretty sure OP means to ask about showing that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: If you mean show that $f(x)$ is bijective, you need to show that for every real number $\alpha \neq 2$, there exists a real number $x \neq 1$ such that $f(x) = \alpha$, and that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g:B\to A\\ g(y)=\frac{y}{y-2}$$
You can easily prove that

- $\forall x\ne 1,\ g(f(x))=x$ $\ $ $\ $(since $f(x)$ is always $\ne2$)
- $\forall y\ne 2,\ f(g(y))=y$

This proves that $f:A\to B$ is bijective and that $g=f^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks sir. from where y/(y-2) came?

Comment: You symbolically solve this for $x$ $$y=\frac{2x}{x-1}\\ y(x-1)=2x\\ yx-y=2x\\ (y-2)x=y\\ x=\frac{y}{y-2}$$ and, afterwards, you can check that it works.

Answer (score 2):

First write $f$ in the equivalent form $f(x)=\frac{2}{x-1}+2$. To see $f$ is injective, assume $f(a)=f(b)$. Then 
$$
\frac{2}{a-1}+2=\frac{2}{b-1}+2
$$
which gives $2(a-1)=2(b-1)$, i.e. $a=b$. To see that it is surjective, let $y$ be in your codomain. Then $x=\frac{2}{y-2}+1$ is a well defined element of your domain with $f(x)=y$. As $f$ is surjective and injective, it is bijective.

Comment: thanks. and what about the elements which are not included in A and B sets?